# What is a mummer?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the *A Song of Ice and Fire* series, what is a **mummer**? The books never explained.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mummer?s=t

Comment: I like to imagine that *mummer's farce* is Dornish rhyming slang for arse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Definition of MUMMER

1
: a performer in a pantomime; broadly : actor
2
: one who goes merrymaking in disguise during festivals

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mummer